# Carrying multivitamins and health supplements from India to UK in check-in baggage

Tags: luggage

I had bought a year's stock of multivitamins and health supplements (Fish oil capsules, Coronil, etc.) in Jan 22. All are in their original packages.

I would be going from India to UK via Dubai/Abu Dhabi/Paris/Amsterdam.

1. Can I keep these multivitamins and health supplements in my check-in baggage?
2. Is there a limit on such items?
3. Is it airline specific?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/bringing-food-into-great-britain? Which airline(s)? Have you checked their guidance?

Comment: If your luggage cannot be checked through from India to the UK, then you'll also have to deal with Customs issues (if any) in Dubai and the EU.

Comment: Do you really need a whole year's supply for your trip?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm going for long term so I need all that supply